# awk search content if it contains content in a list file

Tags: bash, awk

I am meeting some difficulties when using AWK to search a huge csv file (this can be called file1). fortunately, I have a list file (this can be called file2). I can just search the rows that I need basing on the index list file in file2.
however, the file1 is not like any other normal file, it's like:

```
ID1, AC000112;AC000634;B0087;P01116;,ID1_name
ID2, AC000801;,ID2_name
ID3, P01723;F08734;,ID3_name
ID4, AC0014;AC0114;P01112;,ID4_name
...
IDn, AC0006;,IDn_name
IDm, Ac8007; P01167;,IDm_name
```

the index file2 like:

```
AC000112
AC000801
P01112
P01167
```

the desired output should be:

```
ID1, AC000112;AC000634;B0087;P01116;,ID1_name
ID2, AC000801;,ID2_name
ID4, AC0014;AC0114;P01112;,ID4_name
IDm, Ac8007; P01167;,IDm_name
```

if I use

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} ($2 in a)' file2 file1
```

I will get nothing, if I add ";" at the end of each line in file2, I will only get `ID2, AC000801;,ID2_name`. and if I change `$2 ~ a[$1]`, it still didn't work.

So, I was wondering how to change this command to get the desired result. Thanks!

Comment: Do you _need_ to use awk? `grep -Fwf file2 file1`

Comment: since my file1 is quite big (billions of rows), I have no idea which gives me the correct result. but this command and the accept answer worked. Maybe I can answer you when I finished the whole process.

Comment: I was asking whether you were restricted to awk for some other reason. I will post the grep command as an answer. It does achieve your task correctly. It will probably be more efficient than awk too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't restricted to awk, I would use grep for this task:

```
grep -Fwf file2 file1
```

- `-f file2`: use each line of `file2` as a search string.
- `-w`: match whole words only (such that pattern `P01167` won't match `P011670`). Any character other than letters, digits and underscore delimit a word (so `P01167;,` will match).
- `-F`: fixed strings - match the string exactly, such that any regex characters have no special meaning.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the field separator to a comma followed by optional spaces `[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*`

Then you can split the second field of file 1 on a semicolon and optional spaces `[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*` and check if one of those is present in `a`

```
awk -F"[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*" 'NR==FNR{
  a[$1]; next
}
{
  split($2, parts, /[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*/)
  for (i in parts) {
    if (parts[i] in a) {
      print $0; break;
    }
  } 
}
' file2 file1
```

Output

```
ID1, AC000112;AC000634;B0087;P01116;,ID1_name
ID2, AC000801;,ID2_name
ID4, AC0014;AC0114;P01112;,ID4_name
IDm, Ac8007; P01167;,IDm_name
```

Comment: this works for my real work. because there still have some columns with space in it.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -F',|[[:space:]]+|;' '
FNR==NR{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    arr[$i]=$0
  }
  next
}
($0 in arr){
  print arr[$0]
}
' file1 file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk -F',|[[:space:]]+|;' '  ##Setting field separator as comma, space(s), semi-colon here.
FNR==NR{                    ##This condition will be TRUE when file1 is being read.
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){       ##Using for loop to traverse from 2nd field to till last field.
    arr[$i]=$0              ##Creating arr with index of current field, with value of current line.
  }
  next                      ##next will skip all further lines from here.
}
($0 in arr){                ##Checking condition if current line is present in arr.
  print arr[$0]             ##Printing arr with index of $0 here.
}
' file1 file2               ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Short and sweet :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- the search strings only consist of characters and numbers

One `GNU awk` idea where we append word boundary flags to our search patterns and then perform regex comparisons:

```
awk -F',' '
FNR==NR { regs["\\<" $1 "\\>"]; next }
        { for (regex in regs)
              if ($2 ~ regex) { print; next }
        }
' file2 file1
```

This generates:

```
ID1, AC000112;AC000634;B0087;P01116;,ID1_name
ID2, AC000801;,ID2_name
ID4, AC0014;AC0114;P01112;,ID4_name
IDm, Ac8007; P01167;,IDm_name
```